# Is there a way to access NOAA or NASA current and forecast data through a mobile app?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1

I want to build an app that tracks space weather conditions.  I see the NOAA website keeps updating with current and forecast data, on top of that I've seen other websites make use of their data to plot their own graphs.

Is there some way to incorporate the data into a mobile app (specifically for Windows Phone 8 or Windows 8 Store)  to provide live alerts on current conditions?  If so how can I get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get started, you are going to need to build an app that accesses the data via NOAA's web service endpoints. [NOAA Web Services](http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/). You will also need to access the phone's current location as described in this post: [Get phone current location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206956%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Here is the way to get the current location for a windows store app (non-phone): [Windows store app get current location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465135.aspx).

Once you get all those pieces in place, then you should be able to get weather data based on current location.